# How to include a slim api in a html page?

Tags: php, html, api, routes, slim

I have created a slim api. It fetches the db items and displays it. Now how do i include it in a html page? 
This is the api route

```
$app->get('/login/user_table(/:username)', function($username) use ($app){
                  user_table_view($username);

          });
```

This is the html page where i want to insert the api.

```
<div class = "view">
<-- I want the api to be displayed here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries i have found the solution for this.
Use the script to call the api route. It is working fine.

```
<script>
$( "#view" ).load( "http://localhost/login/user_table/001" );
</script>
```